# How to see rejected edits for a post?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I'm in a Facebook group where a user ranted for having his edit rejected. After asking for the link, he said that he did not know that questions had links *(and this made me seriously think that the edit was in fact correctly rejected and that he in fact do not knows how Stack Overflow works)*. But anyway, after talking to him for some time, I finally could obtain the link of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file/5841587#5841587).

However, I did not find any way to see the rejected edits there, if in fact there was any. Is it possible for me to see this? Or I need to get a higher level of reputation? Or only diamond mods can see that? Or after rejected they are tossed in the oblivion to never be found again?

Comment: AFAIK this is only visible to moderators as well as direct participants in the suggested edit review. Here are the two edits: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7171691 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7225206

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you. He said that those are not his edits and that this user is not him. But I am seriously thinking that he is a liar.

Comment: Using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203969/find-the-reviewtasks-for-a-post)  should bring up the reviews done for a post. Just enter the postId and run it. *(Note: SEDE is only updated once a week on Sunday morning UTC, so anything after then won't be visible till it's updated next)*

Comment: @BoltClock Only moderators have a reasonable way to find the link to a rejected edit, but others (with enough rep) can see the edits, and dig for the link in the review queue history (not very practical except for recent edits).

Comment: @BoltClock After talking to him some more, it was clear that he was just a trolling and annoying liar complaining like a child for not accepting being wrong. And he is insisting that he is right and telling the truth even after being presented some glaring and giant evidence to the contrary. Sorry for bothering and thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @Victor: Ah, typical.

Comment: I guess it is this review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7171691

Comment: [The user involved](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4609295/edit-my-name-noob-sry-u-cant) seems to have changed his user bio to a "Goodbye, cruel StackOverflow" rant.

Comment: @BobJarvis I wonder whether his poor English is some form of trolling.

Comment: @BobJarvis he'd be better off changing his bio to "delete me."

Comment: @BobJarvis - From the bio: "_I prefer to ... not have anyone editing what I did_".  Oh, the irony.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can retrieve this information via the StackExchange API:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits#site=stackoverflow&ids=5841587&run=true

(This is not the same as using the Data Explorer, so it gives a current result and so you don't have to wait for the database dump to be updated.)

The two rejected edits were:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7171691

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7225206

Comment: The best part is that one of the reviewers on the first one made their first rejection after ~361 accepts.