# Most asked Question Unclear! Viewing Rejected Edits

Tags: discussion, support, edits

I sometimes edit posts, which may include *grammatical*, *format* or *coding* mistakes. I could do it better because of my better IELTS results. I wanted to know, which edits of mine were rejected, so I searched in google. This is what I got:

1. [How to see rejected edits for a post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287344/how-to-see-rejected-edits-for-a-post) asked one year ago
2. [How can I see all my rejected edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85193/how-can-i-see-all-my-rejected-edits) asked five year ago
3. [My rejected edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) also asked five years ago

but I have to say, it is still unclear to me, exactly how to show my edits which were rejected. I go through the GUI of the Stack Overflow very keenly to find it out but didn't. The rejected ones are somehow mixed with accepted ones. It's very important for me to know, because I want my edits to be more Professional.

The links mentioned, have answers that I was unable to understand. **A simple way through the GUI of Stackoverflow to find out the rejected edits would be appreciated.**

Comment: What is "IELTS"?

Comment: it's International English Language Testing System. Students who want to study abroad, need test like these to go to any foreign countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no list of only the rejected edits; although you could probably make a SEDE query for that, if you wanted to.

You can see the list of all your edits, it's on your profile page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

This is a list of all the edits that you made, including their status: approved, rejected or pending.

You can use the link above, or go to your profile page, select "all actions" and then "edits". You will see a list of your edits, together with their status: "approved edit", "pending edit" or "rejected edit". These texts are links, clicking on them takes you to the edit in question.

Here's a picture. As you've found out, if you have suggested a lot of edits, the list may take more than one page.

[image]

Comment: So i suppose, it's true that, only moderators have access to rejected edits, But i still didn't understand, why they didn't want to show us our rejected edits, i mean if they did, it could have improved out editing techniques. Or the thought that someone may try to downvote the person who rejects the edits, make rejected edits a secret, Right?

Comment: You can see your rejected edits. Go to that list, and look for "rejected edit".  Those things are hyperlinks, so you just click on them to go to the edit itself. I'll update the answer.

Comment: It was showing on another page. Tnkx

Answer (score 11):

This isn't an answer to your question, but the comment I was writing got too long and difficult to read.

After glancing through a few of your recent edits, I wanted to communicate a few concerns with your edits so you can adjust you editing style.

1. Too many of your edits are adding a lot of unnecessary formatting, specifically bolding.  While using **bold** to emphasize a specific word or even phrase is ok, making a point to bold a whole sentence should be done very rarely. Too much formatting can actually make the post more difficult to read, not easier.
2. Your title edits run contrary to typical title writing suggestions.

   - Don't append the language to the front of the title.  The tags on the question already identify the language so it isn't necessary to add it.  It is also part of the markup, so it will appear in the google results without needing to manually add it to the title
   - Good titles are typically sentences or phrases.  Several of the edits you made actually changed a good title.  For example, in https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15154114, the original title good and it was unnecessary to change it.
   - Titles do not have to be in title case, so it isn't necessary to capitalize all nouns.
3. Don't edit bad questions (aka don't polish turds).  They are just wasting everyone's time.  In most cases, an edit from someone other than the original asker is not going to make the question good.  And usually the question is going to get deleted, which means whatever rep you earned will be lost.

Overall, your grammar and spelling fixes have been good and look to be generally helpful, so please keep editing.  You just need to back off on adding a lot of formatting and changing titles.

Some additional suggested reading:

- [Had my title corrected despite taken almost verbatim from "Writing Good Titles" article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285083/had-my-title-corrected-despite-taken-almost-verbatim-from-writing-good-titles)
- [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)
- [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)
- [User adding excessive bolding in otherwise good edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327171/user-adding-excessive-bolding-in-otherwise-good-edits)
- [Should I avoid using bold letters in question body?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311690/should-i-avoid-using-bold-letters-in-question-body)

Comment: I greatly thank you for your suggestions and time. I will try to my fullest follow the guidelines, you provided.

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZulqarnain I see you haven't really taken the guidelines to heart since you are still making edits with the same issues as I raised.

Comment: I do remember it, each time I edit a post, but it will take time to fully master it.