# Afraid of doing edits

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits

I started editing almost two weeks ago, and got 81 approved edits and 12 rejected. During this time, I found many mistakes in my edits (that were removed in the later edits) through questions on Meta.

I read all possible documentation on which posts should be edited. I did it because I wanted to keep my rejected edits low. And here I stand now: When I think a post can be made better through editing, because it has some grammar or layout mistakes, I just stop myself: **No, the mistakes are too little to edit.**

Although I understand (through little experience) which posts must be edited, and that would be the posts with too much grammar and layout mistakes. What I just don't get is **the boundary upon which I have to decide to go for the edit or not.**

I think a rejected edit is a very bad thing to happen, as it possibly waste time of 4-5 people (including me), and also having many rejected edits looks bad on any profile.

This is very important for me to understand, because with these fears, I can't do editing anymore.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the boundary upon which, I have to decide to go for the edit or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Thanks for your searching, but no

Comment: @SyedMZulqarnain Don't answer a question posted in a comment in a comment only. If your post is unclear enough that asking questions is necessary, improve your post (and then leave a comment to questioner that you updated your post, not repeating the missing information).

Answer (score 21):

A quick glance at [the edits you've suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7208263/syed-m-zulqarnain?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) indicates that, rather than being rejected because they are too trivial, they are being rejected because they abuse formatting in such a way that it harms readability.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15192411), you've added **bold** and *italics* for absolutely no reason. Neither of those things needed to be emphasized, and applying this formatting just makes the post uglier and harder to read. That edit happened to be approved, but it shouldn't have been. It was a bad edit.

[This edit was also approved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15190008), and while it does make some improvements to the post, it also has the "superfluous formatting" problem. Fixing the grammar, adding capital letters, removing the initial "So", and so forth are all good edits that improve the post. Adding a bunch of unnecessary formatting is not. Also, this edit missed formatting the output as a blockquote.

[This edit has the same problems, and was rejected because a knowledgeable reviewer reviewed it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15189681). They clicked the "Reject and Edit" button, which is exactly what I would have done.

I don't know why you have such a problem with this. [Someone already pointed it out to you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343366/366904), and [you said that you would try to keep it in mind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343360/most-asked-question-unclear-viewing-rejected-edits#comment445141_343366), but you absolutely have not.

The sad fact is, most of your edits are bad, but getting approved anyway. This sends the wrong message, and is a problem that we really need to solve. It turns out that if you give people an "Approve" button, they can hardly stop themselves from clicking it. I've noticed the same problem in Documentation.

Note that it is not *necessary* for you to suggest edits. If you're having trouble figuring out what makes a good edit, then just stop editing until you figure it out. There are other ways for you to participate on this site, such as by answering questions.

Comment: I am thankful for you to go through all my edits, and point out things, but I asked, "What is the boundary upon which, I have to decide to go for the edit or not."
and your answer is supposed for a question like, " Why my edits, get approved while they are bad, and why they get rejected, while they are good".

Comment: The "boundary" is very simple: does this edit improve the post in a significant way? That's not the problem here, though, so I based my answer on the *actual problem*, rather than your incorrect diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: without disrespect, VERY SIMPLE, is the exact question to be answered. How much grammar or layout mistakes should lead to an edit?

Comment: I don't know what you are wanting. The system enforces a minimum of 6 characters being changed. As long as you are changing more than 6 characters, you are allowed to submit the edit. You have to make a decision regarding whether your edit is improving the post in a significant way. It is obviously a judgment call; no one can give you a more precise answer. If you're unsure, don't submit the edit. More to the point, until you can figure out how formatting is supposed to be used, please stop submitting edits altogether.

Comment: @SyedMZulqarnain Fix grammar and layout mistakes when it would significantly improve the post.

Comment: @Cody gary thank's for your answer in last comment, but I must say, you are very harsh on answers, and the more sad thing is, people like you for that. Guess i have to change my full mind about this community, rather than just edits.

Comment: I don't think Cody is being harsh here just because he's always that way. It seems this is a repeating issue that needs to be addressed directly.

Comment: What is addressed directly? Should there be an addressed indirectly, which i suppose would be more polite one, cause i haven't seen that one.

Am i a criminal now, for this direct address !!

Comment: Now I fear, guys like you more, then rejecting some of my edits. You are just answered, without any co-relation of the question. And for your kind information, this is not a robot typing. This is  human, with english as his third language.

Comment: I have thought to stop editing forever. Thanks everyone for very constructive communications.

Comment: That may be for the best. If you see every constructive comment as an attack rather than taking it to heart, you won't improve and are in no place to edit.

Comment: The first time you were advised about this by psubsee2003, it was in a very nice way. Nor was it harsh the second time rene reminded you of it in a comment. By the third time, with no evidence of change in behavior, I think a bit of harshness has its place. So yeah, I was blunt. I don't have any regrets about that. I'm not a robot, either, so I don't really know what that comment was meant to imply. I don't feel that any of my comments have been *disrespectful* to you. It's a fair point that English is your third language, but (1) formatting ≠ grammar, and (2) not everyone is good at editing.

Comment: "No evidence in behaviour" just Mesmerizing. This world works with practice. Why would someone become expert in days just because he was told so? and $Cody try to read "dale carnegie", just for better comment replys

Comment: "Taking it to heart", hoof, hate this word. " I am in no place to edit ", amazing, Can you show me your diploma while stating that?  @Bart

Comment: No one is asking you to become an expert. They're asking you to *stop introducing pointless formatting*. It is actually *easier* to *not* make things bold than it is to make them bold. There is no evidence that you've slowed down on this or even attempted to change. I'm not a big believer in Carnegie's work, nor in useless platitudes. It seems like you would prefer to make excuses for your own lack of attention than try to improve. I don't have much patience with that. I could show you my diploma, if that would help, but I don't know what that has to do with anything.

Comment: If I keep introducing pointless formatting, A reject option is always available for my edit, must lessen your worries about my edits. Did I ever ask you to help me with my edits. I have 82 approvals, message everyone who approved my edits, and ask them, to stop "introducing pointless formatting". They are also in equal crime as me, oh wait, They have the same rep as you, So what does it make you?

Comment: *"The sad fact is, most of your edits are bad, but getting approved anyway. This sends the wrong message, and is a problem that we really need to solve."* Those approvals are wrong. Yes, everyone who approves invalid edits is wrong, too. I already made that argument. Rep has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Then first solve this problem, since they are creating a wrong concept. And yeah man, Rep has very much thing to do. High reps guys.. Oh man..! and if you want to be personal with only my edits approvals, suits you, but mind also wanna help other million members with same problem, or just me.

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem of people approving invalid edits. Do you? I do know of one way to solve the problem, though: **stop suggesting invalid edits**. Yes, I can see how you were confused, since your edits were getting approved. You should not be confused anymore, though, because I and several others have explained to you how the changes you're making to the formatting of the posts are unwelcome and asked you to stop doing it. Nothing confusing about that. No, rep has absolutely nothing to do with it. I don't know what you're getting at.

Comment: You know a problem, and don't know how to solve it, except answering a question, in which you point out the only asker in the millions of members. Wouldn't be it better with your suggested edits, or you are afraid, people might actually criticize your edits..!

Comment: Try answering my question, with your edits. That would help me alot and i might give you the correct answer tag.

Comment: Sure, I could show you my diplomas @SyedMZulqarnain, but that would be pointless. Because I know what makes or doesn't make a good edit through years of experience. I know, because I listen to what people have told me along the way. If you're here only to hear you're doing it right and somehow the system is at fault ... well, you're out of luck. Take the advice you've been given, and adjust how you edit. If not, you're going to rack up more rejections and at some point may even be prevented from editing altogether. Your choice.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to say in the last two comments. They do not make sense. If you're asking why I don't edit things, then you should be aware that I do. In fact, I make a lot of edits. I'm not interested in the "correct answer tag", I'm interested in improving the site.

Comment: "Along the way", my "along the way" is hardly few days. Oh wait, you did not understand me anymore, right?

Comment: And in those few days you have been given plenty of advice. Listen to it. A good edit is a good edit. And a bad one is a bad one. The amount of experience does not factor into that at all. You can be forgiven for initial mistakes. Not for repeated ones after being told what to do and what not to do.

Comment: I don't understand why it takes you more than a day to follow the advice you've been given. It should take effect on your very next edit.

Comment: I deeply appreciate your concern. My question is a duplicate and i already knoe my answer, so guys thanks a lot, no need for your precious time. i mean if you are not totally free, and you do understand me, thank God

Comment: Let me boil it down to some very simple advice for you: Stop adding bold and cursive formatting to posts. Surely that's something you can understand and apply. Take it from there. Good luck.

Comment: Make sure it is an important edit