# Are there other cases where users were incorrectly blamed not to have done an edit to an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, downvotes, rejected-edits

I'm unhappy with following situation:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097866/access-an-arbitrary-element-in-a-dictionary-in-python) from 2010 about Python has a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097866/access-an-arbitrary-element-in-a-dictionary-in-python/17085251#17085251) from June 2013 implicitly using Python 2.
- On October 2013 in a comment it was mentioned what to do when using Python 3.
- As this comment received many upvotes (today: 87), in June 2019 I edited the answer to make it up to date, but the changes [were rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23360121), so I posted it as an answer.
- In September 2019 nearly the same edits, that I was trying to do, [were made to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17085251/revisions).
- So today my answer was [in the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24611781), earning comments like "This should've been a comment or an edit to that post. Moreover, as this information was already edited in that post, there is no need to keep this redundant answer."

So I was criticized based on false assumptions and downvoted because someone else managed to do something I was hindered in by reviewers.

I accept that this answer is now redundant. For this reason and to avoid further downvotes, I deleted it. But it is a pity that I get blamed for something I was trying to do, but presumably nobody saw (seeing rejected edits [is possible but not convenient](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287344/how-to-see-rejected-edits-for-a-post)).

Is this issue known? Are there similar cases?

Comment: Try not to take it personally. The end goal is to have a good question and set of answers.

Comment: Sadly, probably too many to mention, so this question is *too broad*.

Comment: It shouldn't have been edited in, it should've been a separate answer. Case closed.

Comment: The edits you claim had been made to the question (4th bullet), were actually made to the answer. Major difference.

Comment: Someone was wrong on the internet, so the mob had to beat them with the python 3 stick

Comment: You were right to make a separate answer. [Why would I make a new answer when all I want to do is supplement an existing one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362632/7795130) That's not, as the help center outlines, to ["add updates as the post ages"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), it's a new answer to the question in Python 3.

Comment: That answer received several helpful-votes per month.  At the typical rate that the googlers vote that indicates that it helps about a thousand programmers per month.  That is how important it is what we do.  Until today, it got a DV 13 minutes ago.  Somebody had to prove that life is not fair.

Comment: If the consensus is that the edit is wrong, can someone undelete OP's answer and rollback the edit?

Comment: I don't think anyone has spoken out about them, but there definitely are similar cases. Stack Overflow has been around long enough for disagreements of this nature to be relatively common.

Comment: It is often useful to add a (prepared) comment ***immediately*** after such an answer is posted, containing meta information, such as explaining why it was posted (to preempt downvotes and to occupy the important first comment place). E.g. including links such as in [*Davy M went to fund Monica*'s comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391464/are-there-other-cases-where-users-were-incorrectly-blamed-not-to-have-done-an-ed#comment741099_391464) here.